# send notification if a trigger repeated for third time in zabbix

Tags: zabbix, zabbix-custom-reports

I have several hosts on Zabbix that send to me notifications on slack.
for some triggers severity like warning or average, I would like to receive a notification if a trigger is repeated for the third time.and for other severities like high or disaster I would like to receive a notification every time a trigger happened.
How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

You have to define a single trigger to account the three "events" plus the time range to consider (last 5 checks? last five minutes?), and of course define its severity.

You can define trigger notifications, delays and escalations in the Configuration - Action menu, the [documentation](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/config/notifications/action) explains how to set it up with examples.

You can set up a simple slack notification if a trigger stays up for 5 minutes, then send a SMS to the boss if the trigger is still up after 1 hour etc...